# Remote desktop control without directly using ssh which grants complete root access

Tags: 12.04, remote

Can limited root access of an ubuntu system be made available to another Ubuntu system?

Can an Ubuntu system act as a server and other Ubuntu acts as a client, and can the client give strings of data to server? Whereby the server detects a command and runs it (without using ssh).

**Example:** I am in my cabin. I work in a lab and run tests and see the results. Tests (python codes) run for 2-3 hrs once the python name command is given. The code also generates a log file. I want to see the log file from my cubicle. How can I achieve this. In which direction should I proceed? Is this achievable at all? I have been trying for a week. I tried socket() command

I don't want ssh because there are many systems in lab which are to be controlled and it doesn't make sense to ssh every device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it's possible by using rsh

```
rsh username@FQDN python /home/user/pathtocode/
```

ssh would have been better in few cases but in my present using rsh was best but restricted ssh( giving ssh permissions to access only the folder I want to access is another way)

Good Day 
Help others